# On(Double)Click Table cell

Tags: java, jtable, cell

I keep bumping into javascript questions about this, can't find anything about java.

How can I trigger something when a cell in a jTable is double clicked?

Comment: Use Google to search for what you want to do, try implementing it, and come back when you've tried something. The 6th result in my search for "how to listen for double click events in jtable" yielded [this](http://www.esus.com/docs/GetQuestionPage.jsp?uid=1257). If you tried searches but came up with nothing, put them here so we know you tried to find a solution yourself. This site is not a substitute for a search engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a `MouseListener` on the cell and make a `mouseClicked`-method like this:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if(e.getClickCount()==2){
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this one:
http://www.binpress.com/app/doubleclickdetector/345

I think it is free for non commercial use.